# Link to Product from template file

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I was wondering if it would be possible to link to a product in the footer template?

I don't want to use blocks or anything, just a single href tag linking to a product.

I know there is `<?php echo $this->getUrl('our-story'); ?>` but is this efficient for products

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible you have two alternatives I believe:

Add the product link in:
 `app/design/frontend/{YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE}/{YOUR_THEME_HERE}/template/page/html/footer.phtml`

or you could edit an existing cms block, the footer cms block and include the product link there. I think this is the best solution as you can change this from the admin panel directly without having to change your code.

To get the url of a product you can do this:

```
$product->getProductUrl(true);
```

This will produce something like:

> http://www.yourstore.com/productUrl

Comment: Well for a page, you would use `<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('contact') ?>` but is there no Mage helper for products?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do with a helper. Do you need to load the product and then get the url of the product? If that is the case check my answer I updated it